# How do we customise the password fields not matching in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms

I wanted to know how do we customize the error message that shows up when we enter 2 different passwords in the password1 and password2 fields from the built-in UserCreationForm in Django. I have tried this

```
def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super(CreateUserForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['password2'].error_messages.update({
        'unique': 'Type smtn here!'
    })
```

Am I doing something wrong in this process? In my template, this is the code for the error message.

`<span id="error">{{form.errors}}</span>`

Please tell me if there is another way to do this. I am using model forms.

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']
  def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super(CreateUserForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['password2'].error_messages.update({
        'unique': 'Type smtn here!'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the source code of django's `UserCreationForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L82-L121).

This error message is triggered by `clean_password2()` and uses `self.error_messages['password_mismatch']`. This means you basically have to override `error_messages` in your child form:

```py
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):

    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': 'Type smtn here!',
    }
```

Alternatively, if you want to make sure not to loose possible other entries in `error_messages` dict (though it's currently the only entry), you can also update the dict in the `__init__`:

```py
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.error_messages['password_mismatch'] = 'Type smtn here!'
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Is that supposed to go inside the Meta class or outside? Also, thanks for the answer, I'll try it out!

Comment: outside the Meta.